Revert error when using getConversionRate with PriceConverter.sol file
I am writing a fundMe test file where I run tests for my fundMe solidity contract. I am having a problem concerning calling a function called "getConversionRate" from a PriceConverter file, this takes in USD and converts it to ether currency. Now when I test it in my test file, it reverts. The paths are correct and the code is from Cyfrin Updrafts GitHub repository. But for some reason, it does not work when I run it.
This is my getConversionRate and getPrice function:
function getPrice(AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed) internal view returns (uint256) {
        (, int256 answer, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        // ETH/USD rate in 18 digits
        return uint256(answer * 1e10);
    }

    function getConversionRate(
        uint256 ethAmount,
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed
    ) internal view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice(priceFeed);
        uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 1e18;
        return ethAmountInUsd;
    }

This is my fund function in the fundMe file:
function fund() public payable {
        require(
            msg.value.getConversionRate(s_priceFeed) >= MINIMUM_USD,
            "You need to spend more ETH!"
        );
        s_addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        s_funders.push(msg.sender);
    }

This is my test file code (and yes, SEND_VALUE is more than MINIMUM_USD):
function testFundFailsWithoutEnoughEth() public{
        fundMe.fund{value: SEND_VALUE}();
    }

This is the error I am receiving:
forge test --match-test testFundFunctionFailsWithoutEnoughEth -vvv
[⠢] Compiling...
No files changed, compilation skipped

Ran 1 test for test/FundMeTest.t.sol:FundMeTest
[FAIL. Reason: EvmError: Revert] testFundFunctionFailsWithoutEnoughEth() (gas: 17135)
Traces:
  [17135] FundMeTest::testFundFunctionFailsWithoutEnoughEth()
    ├─ [5164] FundMe::fund{value: 5000000000000000000}()
    │   ├─ [0] 0x694AA1769357215DE4FAC081bf1f309aDC325306::latestRoundData() [staticcall]
    │   │   └─ ← [Stop] 
    │   └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert
    └─ ← [Revert] EvmError: Revert

Suite result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 808.81µs (133.50µs CPU time)      

Ran 1 test suite in 9.26ms (808.81µs CPU time): 0 tests passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped (1 total tests)

Failing tests:
Encountered 1 failing test in test/FundMeTest.t.sol:FundMeTest
[FAIL. Reason: EvmError: Revert] testFundFunctionFailsWithoutEnoughEth() (gas: 17135)

Encountered a total of 1 failing tests, 0 tests succeeded ```



>I tried not importing the PriceConverter.sol file and just inserting the functions directly into the fundMe file but it still did not work and sent back the same revert error.



In the stack trace, it shows that it's reverting when calling the latestRoundData(). Are you deploying the MockV3Aggregator in the getOrCreateAnvilEthConfig() function of your HelperConfig script?

If you can share the link to your GitHub repo, I can try debugging on my end.
